# Generate dummy struct in IDA hexrays

Tags: struct

I remember that hexrays has the option to generate a dummy struct from a pointer. That is if we access a pointer in offsets 0x36, 0x24 it will create a struct with members off24 , off36.

In what cases do I see this option in the menu? Or how to make it appear?
I remember that I got it once and it helped me. But since I don't see it , where it is very logical. So, I guess I don't understand its logic. 
Either this, or it is not present in IDA 7.4 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should right-click and select "reset pointer type". And then you get "make new struct" in the menu.

Comment: Not sure it always works..